# Speed of LINQ to XML query vs Regex on large xml strings?

Tags: regex, linq, linq-to-xml

I have the following query:

```
 Dim elementsWithPossibleCCNumbers As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = 
 xmlTree.Descendants().
 Where(Function(element) element.Attributes().
 Where(Function(attribute) attribute.Value.Length >= 13 
                           AndAlso attribute.Value.Length <=    
 16).
 Where(Function(attribute) Long.TryParse(attribute.Value, numeric)).Count() = 1).    
 [Select](Function(x) x)
```

I originally was searching for attributes using Regex, but I started using LINQ to XML due to some others in the community telling me it is the better route to go.  My only concern is that for larger XML strings, how is the performance with the LINQ to XML queries and is it fast than Regex anyway?

Can I improve the speed of the query?

Comment: Have you measured? How large is your XML, and how fast do you *need* it to be? What do you think the chances of you creating correct, robust code are with regex vs LINQ to XML?

Comment: @JonSkeet - I don't really have an definite size since it varies, but one of the largest is 29,123 characters or 1332 words.  It doesn't need to be blazing fast, but this method gets hit every time an xml request hits a web service, so I am just curious.  I did not get a chance to benchmark it yet.

Comment: It sounds like your priorities are wrong then. Write the simplest code you have confidence in, benchmark it, and *then* worry about performance if it's not good enough.

Comment: @JonSkeet - The code works and I am confident in it. I was just interested if anyone knew if LINQ2XML was really slow for larger documents. What is the best way to benchmark it?  Also, do you have any code improvements to the query?

Comment: 30K doesn't count as "large". As for how to benchmark it: run the query several times (enough for measurement to be okay) and time it. As for improving the query: don't use `Long.TryParse`, use the explicit conversion to `Nullable(Of Long)` that `XAttribute` provides.

Comment: @JonSkeet - That is the largest file I found, but I guess it is not so much a question of the size of the file, but the volume of files coming in such as 1000 30K files.   How would I modify the query to use Nullable(Of Long)?

Comment: Then that's a different matter - you asked about "larger documents" which isn't the same thing as "lots of little documents". Test what you're *actually interested in*. As for modifying the query - I don't know enough VB, but I'd expect whatever conversion operator you normally use to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The primary concern is that regexp is fundamentally the wrong tool for processing XML files. It is far too easy to trick regexp into returning wrong results to you, for example by adding a `CDATA` section. The speed is by far the secondary concern: it is impossible to even tell if XML is well-formed with a regex, let alone processing corner cases correctly.

Now to answer your question, the speed depends a lot on the structure of your regular expression. It is possible to construct a file/regexp combination where regexp would be faster, and another pair of file/regexp where the LINQ2XML route would be faster. But LINQ2XML would still be reasonably fast, and it will most likely be more correct.

Comment: Exactly, I had regex that was working, but there were so many corner cases that were driving me nuts, so that is why I went ahead with LINQ2XML.

Comment: Would you consider http://blog.dreamlabsolutions.com/post/2008/12/04/LINQ-to-XML-and-LINQ-to-XML-with-XPath-performance-review.aspx a valid linq for benchmarking results?

Comment: @Xaisoft The blog is comparing LINQ2XML to LINQ2XML w/XPath, and he correctly concludes that XPath is a major slowdown. The raw speed almost does not matter, because you could get much better results by using a faster CPU than what this guy had three years ago.

Comment: Are there any improvements you would make to the query in my post?  I am trying to bench mark it now using StopWatch?

Comment: @Xaisoft Using `TryParse` may not be the fastest way to find out if your 13..16-digit string is a number. Regexp may come in handy there: you could write a `Function(attribute)` that checks `attribute.Value` against the `"\d{13,16}"` expression. Make sure to prepare your regexp before going into LINQ2XML to avoid repeated parsing costs of the regular expression, though.